# R bar graph with error bars for multiple variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am aiming a bar graph with pollutants' names on the y-axis and the concentrations on the x-axis.  For each pollutant, there would be 3 bars representing average concentration during the phases (1,2, and 3).  Error bars should be added that show the maximum measured concentration for each pollutant during each phase.

Here is my data:

```
dput((head(data,100)))
structure(list(phase = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), X = c(2.2, 2.6, 
3.5, 2.7, 3.1, 3.2, 1.7, 1.8, 2.5, 1.4, 3.4, 4.1, 3.8, 3.2, 0.8, 
0.8, 0, 0, 0, 1.3, 0, 1.7, 2.1, 1.2, 1.7, 2.5, 1.8, 1.7, 1.2, 
1.3, 1.4, 0.9, 1.4, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 3.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0.7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1.2, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 0.8, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 0, 0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CH4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.99, 2.06, 2.08, 2.13, 2.2, 2.48, 
2.61, 2.49, 2.44, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.99, 2.06, 2.08, 
2.13, 2.2, 2.48, 2.61, 2.49, 2.44, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1.99, 2.06, 2.08, 2.13, 2.2, 2.48, 2.61, 2.49, 2.44, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.99, 
2.06, 2.08)), .Names = c("phase", "X", "CH4"), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here is what I've tried:

```
#define summarySE function
summarySE <- function(data=NULL, measurevar, groupvars=NULL, na.rm=FALSE,
                      conf.interval=.95, .drop=TRUE)
```

I try to use `ggplot` but I end of with single bar for one pollutant. What is the missing point?

Comment: There are no pollutants in your data, just `phase`, `X` and `CH4`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I am sorry for confusion. Pollutants are X and CH4. thank you